# SoXt configure error 'x11 lib' in mac os x 10.12

Tags: macos, x11, libraries, configure

When i was configure SoXt in my macbook, there happen error in running config Just few second later.

> configure: error: need to able to compile and link against X11 libraries

I'm already installed XQuartz latest version.
so, i tried to fix this problem, such as location to x11 library. but doesn't worked.

any idea?

this is my configure error log.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles...     
no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
.....

checking windows.h usability... no
checking windows.h presence... no
checking for windows.h... no
checking for function name variable for CPP compiler... __func__
checking for function name variable for C compiler... __func__
checking if user is simian... probably not
checking whether gcc accepts -W... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -Wall... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -Wno-unused... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -Wno-multichar... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -W... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -Wall... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -Wno-unused... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -Wno-multichar... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -Woverloaded-virtual... yes
checking for GetEnvironmentVariable() function... no
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) yes
checking for the dl library... yes
checking for X... libraries /usr/X11/lib, headers
checking whether -R must be followed by a space... neither works
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
configure: error: need to able to compile and link against X11 
libraries
```

Cheers.